# aws-cli command `aws s3 sync` producing error CompleteMultipartUpload multipart completion is already in progress

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli, ceph

```
aws --endpoint http://endpoint-to-a-ceph-s3-interface s3 sync local s3://bucket/path/

upload failed: file_60mb to s3://bucket/path/file_60mb An error occurred (InternalError) when calling the CompleteMultipartUpload operation (reached max retries: 4): This multipart completion is already in progress
Command exited with non-zero status 1
```

Running the s3 command above is intermittently producing the CompleteMultipartUpload error. This is pointing to a Ceph/S3 interface (A RedHat distributed filesystem), not AWS/S3.

So far I've tried `export AWS_MAX_ATTEMPTS=20` (that appears to have no effect because it still only retries 4 times), and `export AWS_RETRY_MODE=adaptive` (no discernable effect).

Comment: would be nice if you use `--debug` and update your post.

Comment: Working on that! Thanks @saranjeetsingh

Comment: Hi @DavidParks, I used aws C++ SDK and met the same problem, did you figure it out? Thank you!

Comment: @Tinyden, sorry, I can't say I ever figured this out, the problem seems that it went away on its own for me.

Answer (score 0):

We believe we have an answer to what is happening here. This bug tracker issue appears to explain it:

https://tracker.ceph.com/issues/53808

What we think happens is:

1. An HTTP request is made to complete the multi-part-upload.
2. The request is received on the S3 server and the multi-part-upload completes successfully.
3. The HTTP request times out so the client doesn't receive the confirmation even though the multi-part-upload completed successfully.
4. The client retries the request due to the timeout, which produces the exception because the first request was received by the server.